# Не работает order by после group by SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Дана таблица, см скриншот.
Я пытаюсь сгруппировать модели по их количеству в наличии, а потом отсортировать по количеству в наличии. Но order by не срабатывает после группировки и сортировка не происходит. Как я могу после группировки все таки сделать сортировку?

```
select model, count(*) count_model
from PC
group by model
order by count_model desc
```

На выходе происходит это:

[image: Вот что на выходу]

[image: Таблица]

Comment: Все отлично работает http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fae62b/1 приведите воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: На Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (15.0) не работает

Comment: мой запрос приведен в теле вопроса

Comment: Работает https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=86dc718cc8b06c34f5559534357fab75

Comment: Судя по всему на sql-ex.ru проблемы) Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Строго говоря были некоторые диалекты sql где в order by нельзя было указывать алиасы из фразы select (но они выдавали явную ошибку синтаксиса, а не кривой результат), тогда это лечилось повторением самого count т.е.`order by count(*) desc`. Но сейчас практически все БД все таки позволяют как вы написали и в том числе sql-server. попробуйте, вдруг sql-ex так поймет :)

Comment: Еще можно попробовать `ORDER BY 2 DESC`